# Hypermedia implementation for J2ME Client

Tags: lwuit, codenameone, hateoas

I'm supposed to parse information from a JSON string to build a UI for an app. However the data contains hypermedia (HATEOAS) instead of the more traditional approach of having all the data in the JSON string. How would I go about fetching this info in LWUIT or CodenameOne?

```
//Sample response:
{
"user_details": "https://mysite.io:8085/users/15",
"user_roles": "https://mysite.io:8085/users/15/roles",
"allocations": "https://mysite.io:8085/allocations/15"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codename One has a builtin `JSONParser` class that can parse such responses easily. It also has some 3rd party classes to parse JSON.